# How to get the first Star Medal in S8-4 in Super Mario 3D Land for the Nintendo 3DS?

Tags: super-mario-3d-land

I am trying to 100% Super Mario 3D Land for the Nintendo 3DS (which I have been trying to do since 2 days ago) and am currently working on 100%ing Special World 8.

While I am aware that I still need to 100% S8-2 and S8-3, this is not my problem currently.

My current problem is getting the first Star Medal in S8-4. I have found and gotten the last two, however I am unable to find the location of the first one.

I think it might be somewhere near the beginning of the level, but I am unsure where specifically.

So my question is: where would I be able to find the first Star Medal in S8-4? I’m unsure where I should look.

[Photo of progress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYvMw.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's located on the first "bolt" where Kamek shoots at you, screw it to the right to find the first medal.

[image]